# Pinning to Word Documents Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, documents, pin

[image]I recently and regrettably had to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and am having trouble with pinning a Word document onto the Word Document program (2016 version) on the task bar.

Previous in Windows 7, I would right click on the current opened document and I had the ability to pin the document, or the document would should up in the rently opened files when I right clicked on the word document program on my task bar and I would be able to right click on the recently opened document and pin the document on to my pinned document list that way.

How do I go about doing this in Windows 10???

As of right now, I can only remove/delete pinned documents from my pinned list, but I cannot add anything new, and when I right click on the Word document program on the taskbar I cannot conveniently see recently opened word docs. Is there a way to fix / circumvent this??

Thank you.

Comment: I can pin documents within Word. Open a desired document then click on Open again and click on the Pin icon. Please advise if that helps.

Comment: Nope, this did not answer my inquiry, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

So I actually had to "update" to the newest version of Microsoft Office unfortunately.
Then I realized that pinning in W10 was different from W7 where you can not fluidly move in between each of the pinned objects, and the only way to do so was if you remove the stuff you don't want and then put in the thing you want.

In other words, you need to come up with a pre-existing / think of the correct arrangement and order before pinning items..which I honestly don't understand why MS would do something as stupid as this.

Then I changed the limit of the how many pinned objects you can have since at default it is at 13 or 15 can't remember, either way, I made a new file in regedit and increased the size to 60. So everything is working O.K. for now.

Comment: Would you mind adding what you did in regedit to increase the  count of pinnable objects? TY for your solution!

Comment: So here is what you do:
Go to Regedit.
Then Find this exact file path under Microsoft in Regedit in the picture below.
You have to create a new file, name is exactly as I have it written for value name, and pick base as hexadecimal.

https://i.postimg.cc/8zRMpkRD/jumplist-LI.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is pretty easy to do. First of all open all the documents you have or want pinned. Order at this point doesn't matter. Then upin them all, and repin in the order you want from the recent documents part. Not intuitive, but takes like 10 seconds.